# Workbook renaming when opened

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am writing a module that opens each workbook in a folder and copies some information from it. It runs smoothly on most files in the folder, but some workbooks appear with different names when opened by the module. My code is as follows

```
Sub AutoUpdate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 10).Value = Now()
'refreshes timestamp
Dim counter As Integer
Dim form
form = Dir("Macintosh HD:Users:user:Documents:Folder:")
'Finds first form in folder
counter = 1
Do Until form = ""
    Workbooks.Open ("Macintosh HD:Users:user:Documents:Folder:" & form)
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 1).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("D3").Value
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 2).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("D5").Value
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 3).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("D1").Value
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 4).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 5).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("L69").Value
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 6).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("K36").Value
    Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 7).Value = Workbooks(form).Sheets(1).Range("C37").Value
    Workbooks(form).Close
    counter = counter + 1
    form = Dir
    'cycles through all forms
Loop
Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Range("A:G").Sort Key1:=Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("C:C"), Order2:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlSortRows
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

This pulls the data from the first 45 workbooks, then returns "runtime error 9 subscript out of range." The open workbook appears with the name reading as the file name with two seemingly random digits appended. When I manually open the file the name reads as the file name.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?  The random chars in the name would make the `Workbooks(form).Close` fail. I also just noticed that your `Sort` statement is referencing 2 different worksheets when you specify the keys.  Notice `Sheets(2)` and `Sheets(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Workbooks(form)` to access the data, you should simply use `ActiveWorkbook` after you have opened each file.  You can also close the open workbook with `ActiveWorkbook.Close`

You could also define a variable like this:-  `Dim wb As Workbook` and then assign the variable with the opened workbook like this:-

`set wb = Workbooks.Open ("Macintosh HD:Users:user:Documents:Folder:" & form)`

Then you can reference the workbook using `wb`.  e.g.

```
Workbooks("Inventory.xlsm").Sheets(2).Cells(counter, 1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("D3").Value
```

and then close it like this:-

```
wb.Close
```

Don't forget to be a good resource citizen and release the memory with this at the end:

```
set wb = Nothing
```